# com.python.util.PythonInterpreter: cannot set a python variable to a String

Tags: java, python, jython, codec

I have an odd problem.  So I am writing a program that uses Python for a simple user scripting interface.  But to keep my question simple...I am trying to use PythonInterpreter.set to set a variable in the Python interpreter to a String value.  But when I set it I get this exception:

```
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

The following is my code:

```
package demo;

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();

        String greeting = "Jesus Christ";
        Integer times = 6;

        pi.exec("actor = 'Lucy'");
        pi.set("greeting", greeting);
        pi.set("times", times);
        pi.exec("print '%s %s' % (greeting, actor)");
        pi.exec("print \"%s %s \\n\" % (greeting, actor) * times");
        System.out.println("RESULT: " + pi.eval("actor == 'Lucy'"));
        System.out.println("ACTOR:  " + pi.get("actor"));
    }
}
```

If you need to see the pom file for my project, I can include it, but really I just have the Jython 2.5.0 library installed.  I am wondering if I needed to install something else on my system other than having maven install this library for me.  I do have Python installed on this computer, and PYTHON_HOME setup in the environment variables.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The line:

```
pi.set("times", times);
```

...works just fine.

But...

```
pi.set("greeting", greeting);
```

does not.  I imagine it has something to with times being a primitive data type and greeting being a String.

Comment: Try Jython 2.5.3 or 2.7-b1. Your problem looks like the one reported here: http://bugs.jython.org/issue1458